# Google Analytics large list using regex limits

Tags: google-analytics

in the transactions tab, I'm analyzing a large segment of data and I am trying to use a large number of transaction (~20k) ids and applying a regex filter; to analyze the source/medium of those transactions, like this 
`id1|id2|id3` but GA will not accept my filter beyond a certain number of transaction IDs and will throw an error

> Analytics has encountered an unexpected condition and cannot fulfill your request.

- is there an exact number of items that can be used in the filters?
- is there any other way to segment a list of orders other than going to the transactions tab? and with no limits?

Answer (score 0):

You can use 256 characters in a Filter pattern so, for a use of the filters as you request, the ideal is to export the data to Excel and use the relative formulas.